# Bluetooth uC SoM w/ antennae array for AoA direction finding? (or antenna array daughter card?)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, nordic

I need Bluetooth AoA on custom PCB I'm designing to have manufactured & populated at a pcb shop.  Using nrf53 because its well documented, Nordic's support seems good, and I've used the toolchain in the past.  The carrier board is space-constrained, but I'm a relative novice EE and PCB wise, so I feel pretty constrained to using a a pre-qualified** SoM that solves the microcontroller's power and analog/RF requirements.

AoA for bt5.1+ requires a phased array antennae*.  There are numerous SoM's available (just a few available on Digikey: [Fanstel BT40](https://web.archive.org/web/20230326152140/https://www.fanstel.com/bt40f-nrf5340), [Laird BL5340](https://web.archive.org/web/20230320121109/https://www.lairdconnect.com/wireless-modules/bluetooth-modules/bluetooth-5-modules/bl5340-series-multi-core-bluetooth-52-802154-nfc-modules) and [BL653](https://web.archive.org/web/20230320131505/https://www.lairdconnect.com/wireless-modules/bluetooth-modules/bluetooth-5-modules/bl653-series-bluetooth-51-802154-nfc-module), [u-blox NORA-B1](https://web.archive.org/web/20230531224752/https://content.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/NORA-B1_DataSheet_UBX-20027119.pdf) and some others) - but as best I can tell **none of them offer the multiple antennae required** in any sku.

Am I taking the right approach here, and can you point me to any suitable modules?  If none exist, I still ~need to use a SoM for the nrf53 - is there a pre-built array "daughter card" available from any reputable source?  I suppose I could attempt something [like](https://web.archive.org/save/https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/guides/hardware-design-test-and-measuring/b/nrf5x/posts/general-pcb-design-guidelines-for-nrf53-series) [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20231006192619/https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/53018/matching-antenna-on-circular-board) utilizing say a Johanson matched [antenna](https://web.archive.org/web/20220615182827/https://www.johansontechnology.com/datasheets/2450AT42B100/2450AT42B100.pdf) and [filter](https://web.archive.org/web/20231006192711/https://www.johansontechnology.com/datasheets/2450FM05A0045001T/2450FM05A0045001T.pdf), but this really seems unwise given my skillset and available cycles.

Thank you!

`*` this is how the docs phrase it; not exactly accurate as I understand the term - I would expect a phased-array antennae to be multiple elements all clocked (eg simultaneously) into individual receive buffers ... it appears that at least for [Nordic](https://web.archive.org/web/20230601060412/https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF_Connect_SDK/doc/latest/nrf/samples/bluetooth/direction_finding_connectionless_rx/README.html) the reference solution uses [analog antennae multiplexing](https://web.archive.org/web/20231006190245/https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fnwp_036%2FWP%2Fnwp_036%2Fantenna_switching.html).  That's all above my EE level (lacking! :) ) but thought it's relevant to point out here.

`**` at this point this is proof of concept, it's not strictly necessary to have this *FCC* qualified, although that's nice; I mean just functionally qualified, particularly on the RF side.